# Why does this JSX cause an "excessive stack depth" error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx, tsx

I am using Next.js' built in TypeScript (4.2.3) support to compile the following React component.

```
const Component = (): JSX.Element => {
  const categories = ['Fruit', 'Vegetables'];

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>All</li>
      {categories.map((category) => (
        <li key={category}>{category}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

The `categories.map(...)` gets underlined in VSCode with the following TypeScript error:

> Excessive stack depth comparing types 'FlatArray<Arr, ?>' and 'FlatArray<Arr, ?>'. ts(2321)

If I remove the first list item, the error disappears:

```
const Component = (): JSX.Element => {
  const categories = ['Fruit', 'Vegetables'];

  return (
    <ul>
      {categories.map((category) => (
        <li key={category}>{category}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

Please can someone help me understand why this error is occurring? Or is it a bug?

Comment: Does this fix your issue? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43249

Comment: @RohitKashyap yes, thank you! This appears to be a bug with TypeScript 4.3.0-dev.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the GitHub issue @RohitKashyap linked (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43249), this appears to be a bug with TypeScript 4.3.0-dev.

For now I have reverted to 4.2.3 to resolve this issue.